# Comparing items in lists within same indices python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, for-loop

I want to compare between 2 lists and extract the contents

```
colours = ["yellow", "light pink", "red", "dark blue", "red"]

items = ["the sun is yellow but the sunset is red ",
         "the pink cup is pretty under the light", 
         "it seems like the flower is red", 
         "skies are blue",
         "i like red"]
```

Expected result:

```
["yellow", "pink light", "red", "blue", "red"]
```

If there are two words in the colours list, the item will be broken down into two words.
As you can see, the order of the words in colours ("pink", "light") is not important as the two words are broken into individual words and then compared individually in the sentences. Note that in the first item in items, although there is "red" in the colours list, I do not want to extract it because the "red" is in different index from the item's index.

for the 4th index which are "dark blue" and "skies are blue", the result should display only "blue" because dark is not present in the items.

I've tried to code but the results that I get is the lists are not compared within same indices by once, instead it loops through many times, hence the repeated "red".

```
colours=["yellow","light pink","red"," dark blue","red"]

items=["the sun is yellow but the sunset is red ","the pink cup is pretty under the light", "it seems like the flower is red", "skies are blue","i like red"]

for i in colours:

y=i.split() #split 2 words to 1 word
    for j in y:
    #iterate word by word in colours that have more than 1 word
        for z in items: 
            s=z.split() #split sentences into tokens/words
            for l in s:
            #compare each word in items with each word in colours
                if j == l:
                    print j
```

Result:

```
yellow
light
pink
red
red
red
blue
red
red
red
```

Correct Result:

```
yellow
pink light 
red
blue
red
```

Comment: Is the order of the results important, e.g. 'pink light' vs 'light pink' for the second item in the expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `zip`, you could do much easier:

```
colours=["yellow","light pink","red"," dark blue","red"]

items=["the sun is yellow but the sunset is red ","the pink cup is pretty under the light", "it seems like the flower is red", "skies are blue","i like red"]

lst = []
for x, y in zip(colours, items):
    word = ''
    for c in y.split():
        if c in x:
            word = word + ' ' + c
    lst.append(word.strip())

print(lst)
# ['yellow', 'pink light', 'red', 'blue', 'red']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following list comprehension:

```
print([' '.join(w for w in i.split() if w in c.split()) for c, i in zip(colours, items)])
```

This outputs:

```
['yellow', 'pink light', 'red', 'blue', 'red']
```

Comment: why do you need the second call to `split`?

Comment: One `split` for `items`, and the other `split` for `colours`. If the OP does not care about matching words and only needs substring match then there's no need for `c.split()` (for `colours`).

Comment: if say `items[0]` is `'"the sun is yellowish but the sunset is red "'` you do not return `'yellow'`. And I think that is correct. I will delete my answer.

Comment: Thank you,the result is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Using sets to test for membership should be much faster, with a caveat:

```
>>> [' '.join(set(colour.split()) & set(item.split())) 
     for colour, item in zip(colours, items)]
['yellow', 'pink light', 'red', 'blue', 'red']
```

The caveat is that sets are unordered, so 'pink light' could come out as 'light pink'.